# Retrieve delivery fees from Prestashop Web Services

Tags: web-services, prestashop

I am using Prestashop Web Services to manage my e-shop from an iOs app. I already retrieved my products but I did not find a way to get my delivery fees. I check the "carriers" resource but there is not any price indicated, neither any id that could lead to another resource. Same thing about the "price_ranges" resource, there are all my ranged defined in my carriers, but no one has a price.
Does anyone know how I can retrieve my delivery fees ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find delivery fees in the delivery table.
You'll also need range_price and range_weight tables.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought this table was about deliveries and not the fees.